# AZURE ACS - Windows Live ID - How do I get the email and name of the authenticated user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, acs

Here is the scenario:

MVC 3 application runing in AZURE Dev enviroment
Authentication in AZURE ACS implemented the same way found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127794.aspx

I am trying to get the users name, and email, but I can't find a way to configure the "Claim Rule", in a way that I would get a clear text value, instead I get a string that seems to be encrypted.
So can I configure the rule in a way that I get it in clear text? Or can I unencrypt the value returned?
Is any of this possible or am I looking at the wrong thing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIRC, it is against Windows Live privacy policy to release the user's name or email address as claims (unlike Gmail or Yahoo!).  As such, it is not possible to get those claims from Live (unless you happen to be Microsoft).

The only value you can get is called a name identifier.  It is unique per RP domain (i.e. it is not a single value per LiveID, but differs by domain).  This is also intentional so that you cannot have different websites collaborating to track a user.  Typically, you would get the name identifier (called a PUID) and then stick that in your database somewhere so you know that you have seen it before.  Then the user registers on your side with name, email, etc. and you correlate that with the PUID.

On the other hand, LiveId also supports OAuth2, so you can get whatever user profile information you need from the user (with his/her consent). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx).

Comment: What's stopping you from building a custom STS with a few lines of code that uses the server-side connect API to append email + full-name as additional claims? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243649.aspx

Comment: This lists all the providers and their details in Azure ACS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185971.aspx and no like dunnry said you can only get the nameidentidier and identiyprovider claims from Windows Live, view this for verification. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185944.aspx

Answer (score 8):

This is a total #FAIL on the part of Microsoft. The users, when logging into your site using Google or other providers, they have to accept first. Then they simply pass the basic information to the site, the site uses it, and everyone is happy.

BTW you can get it from the user with behind-the-scenes code pages but it's not seamless for the user, requires a manual process, but nonetheless the LiveID system is not more secure for doing this, it's simply broken.

Answer (score 1):

Possible but it requires a bit of code for a custom sts:

https://gist.github.com/1867792

Code doesn't build and dependencies aren't included... but it's largely based off an early thinktecture starter site ported to MVC4 with changes shown above.

Answer (score 0):

This blog discusses creating a custom windows live STS provider and then incorporating it as a trusted identity provider in SharePoint.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/03/01/finally-a-useful-way-to-federate-with-windows-live-and-sharepoint-2010-using-oauth-and-saml.aspx

Unfortunately it seems like the Azure team just don't seem to understand that people may want to actually get something useful back from windows live id.

You can also remove windows live Id as an option for sign on by clicking on it in the Identity providers, and then un-checking the association with your relying party.

(Really weird that you can't choose to delete it =P)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of techniques for querying the Live servers for additional information about authenticated users (provided of  course that they have given consent). You can do some simple customization to your site using some client side javascript to fetch the information as shown in the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826534.aspx.

It's also possible, although a bit more involved, to query the Live servers from your server side code. The example application described at http://dominicbetts.github.io/waad-acs-sample/index.html shows one possible approach in an MVC4 application.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a way, a bit convoluted, but by becoming the broker and using live connect API, you can achieve this functionality.

Please see: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Get-Azure-ACS-work-40d588cc#content

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged due to the fact that Microsoft can change its links and cause this answer to become invalid. Even a simple code sample or skeleton would help.

Answer (score -1):

Its possible by iFrame Trick.

```
<iframe src="https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignout1.0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

this wont redirect you to MSN page