# What is the best way to use live id authentication with azure based asp.net mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, acs, windows-live-id

What is the best way to use live id authentication with azure based asp.net mvc project?

I find the options
1) With in Live SDK, there are options like REST, JavaScript, C# etc.
2) Since my project will be hosted in azure, there is another way "Securing Web Applications with ACS" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185928.aspx

Please suggest the design and also support with pros when an particular approach is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to work with ACS. Not only is it intended for this purpose, there's a fully worked up example at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185975.aspx

which will give you a flying start.

ACS, and Windows Identity Foundation in general, lets you take the approach of separating identity verification from your application altogether. This saves a ton of code and means that you have much less "plumbing" to support.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy :) Can we get information like first name, last name, email id, company etc from ACS claim?

Comment: I believe that depends on your IP (identity provider). It's worth getting hold of a copy of Programming Windows Identity Foundation -- this gives an excellent introduction to how ACS works.

Comment: From Live ID you can't get anything other than a unique id, not even email address. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871960/azure-acs-windows-live-id-how-do-i-get-the-email-and-name-of-the-authenticat